# User-defined Product with blocked variable and syntax hightlighting

Tags: function-construction, products

I want to define a new `Product` but for `NonCommutativeMultiply`, which I do something like this:

`NCMProduct[expr_, iterator_] := 
 NonCommutativeMultiply @@ Table[expr, iterator]`

Is there any way for Mathematica to `Block` the iterator automatically to the scope of `NCMProduct` like it would for `Product`?

So then I could use things like:

`i = 3;
NCMProduct[f[i], {i, 5}]
Product[f[i], {i, 5}]`

In this case, `Product` will `Block` out `i` and the fact that I have assigned to `i` doesn't matter, but `NCMProduct` doesn't know that `i` is going to be `Block`ed inside its definition, and hence I get `Table::itraw`, which isn't the behaviour I want.
I'd also like to have nice syntax highlighting for my `NCMProduct` showing that `i` is `Block`ed in the front end if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is an evaluation leak, which is fixed with:

```
SetAttributes[NCMProduct, HoldAll];

NCMProduct[expr_,iterator_] := NonCommutativeMultiply @@ Table[expr, iterator]
```

Your example:

```
i = 3;
NCMProduct[f[i], {i, 5}]
```

> f[1] ** f[2] ** f[3] ** f[4] ** f[5]

As for syntax coloring, the easiest thing to do is to copy the syntax information for [`Product`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product):

```
SyntaxInformation[NCMProduct] = SyntaxInformation[Product];
```

Here is a screen shot showing the syntax coloring:

[image]

Comment: Excellent thanks!